How do we use "be on the verge of"?
Can we use "be on the verge of something" with time adverbials? For instance

I am on the verge of going there in one hour

I am on the verge of going there next year


Is 2 also wrong because one year is far way from here and "on the verge" implies something soon?

Have you looked up the meaning of on the verge of? Clearly, both your sentences are nonsense.

@KateBunting be really close to do something. Like "be about to"

Exactly. So you can't be 'about to' do something in a year's time.

@Kate Bunting What about soon or 30 minutes?

If you're 'on the verge of' doing something, you are going to do it soon, so there is no reason to include the word soon, or any other time clause. The exact timescale implied depends on the circumstances. If you are on the verge of fainting, you are likely to faint now. If you are on the verge of moving house, it might be in a few days or weeks - it's going to happen so soon that you can't concentrate on anything else.

@KateBunting - maybe, being on the verge is dependent on the time-scale? I can be on the verge of finishing a glass of sherry that I will finish in three minutes, and I think the Earth can be on the verge of climate disaster if it might happen in twenty or fifty years.

@MichaelHarvey - That's what I said, only I expressed it the other way round.

Your sentence is mixing elements that don't make sense together. Present tense "am" doesn't make sense with "on the verge" and "in one hour".
Consider the similar, somewhat synonymous preposition, about:

Hi, Marta. It's Tim. Do you have a moment to talk about the neighborhood meeting?
-- I'm about to leave for work. Can I phone you back around lunch time?

"about to leave for work" means, I intend to leave home to go to work in the next few minutes. My leaving for work is imminent.  I am ready to go out the door.
Now, let's replay that conversation, adding in a few of the elements you're using:

Hi, Marta. It's Tim. Do you have a moment to talk about the neighborhood meeting?
-- I'm about to leave for work in two hours. Can I phone you back around lunch time?

Similarly, on the verge has this sense of "imminence". It means "close to the edge or boundary of something", with the figurative meaning of "about to cross into new territory or about to enter into a new state (of existence)". Another step or two, and you will have crossed over.

Scientists are on the verge of a major advance in the treatment of memory loss.
Scientists are on the verge of making a major advance in the treatment of memory loss.

Now, add in the kind of "delay" you're using:

Scientists are on the verge of making a major advance in the treatment of memory loss in the next twenty years.

Or something like this:

The teacher is speaking so harshly to the children that they are on verge of tears an hour from now.

The time phrase must be compatible with the notion of imminence, and the tense must also be compatible.  The present tense isn't compatible with "an hour from now" in this construction.

The teacher is speaking so harshly to the children that they will soon be on the verge of tears.


" I'm about to leave for work in two hours. Can I phone you back around lunch time?" So that's good or wrong?

@marta It means we would be better off not inviting you to the neighborhood meeting, because your sense of time is wacko.  If you were taking a flight and needed to prepare, perhaps. But if you're just leaving home on a typical daily commute to work, "about to leave in two hours" is incongruous  You must have a context where "two hours" equates to "imminent" for that to be justified.

"We're about to launch our IPO in two hours, and the lawyers want to change some of the terms?"

Lauching takes long time so that's why it's fine?

The preparations for an IPO can take a year, and so the launching of an IPO becomes imminent days or weeks in advance of the launch.  on the verge of and about to .... have relative temporal meaning, and so when used with absolute expressions of time, those time units must  equate to an interval that is relatively appropriate in context.

"I'm about to become a police officer. I have been training 4 years to acheive my dream." Goo?

Is that a valid use?

@marta  That is a valid and idiomatic sentence, but it doesn't illustrate the issue with the temporal unit's appropriateness.  The interval in question is the time between the utterance and the action.  Here's another example of mismatched time unit: "I'm about to graduate in two years."

my fault. I somehow forgot to include it. I meant. ""I'm about to become a police officer in 2 months. I have been training 4 years to achieve my dream." Correct?

@marta Yes, that is a good sentence.  Only a very minor non-grammatical error. It is  the convention to spell out small numbers, "in two months".
